# How to check available keyboards on android phone?

Tags: android, keyboard

I developed an android application, that uses farsi characters. Some android phones like Samsung supported farsi characters and installed Farsi Keyboard on the phone, But HTC phones do not support these.

I just want to check on each phone that my application wants to run on it, **is Farsi keyboard installed, or not?**
If I know that, I will reshape farsi characters for HTC phone.